# python fail to display list of modules

Tags: ubuntu, python-2.7

I have new installation of ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I have python 2.7 and installed python 3.3 as python3 up to now did not have problems, but installation is fairly new. When I try to check modules I installed by using `help('modules')` I have an error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk

** (python:20929): CRITICAL **: pyg_register_boxed: assertion `boxed_type != 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type `GdkDevice'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no idea how to interpret this output and what I should do. Obviously if there is some problem I want to fix it now after OS installation and do not wait until will loose a work. Anyone had similar issue and know what should be done?

Comment: It looks like a problem with PyGTK. I get the same warnings on Arch Linux, but nothing segfaults.

Comment: @Blender did you try to resolve it? I have not idea what I should do. just checked in synaptic it looks I have libraries for GTK instlled

Comment: It doesn't bother me at all. I don't work with PyGTK.

Comment: But how it is connected with one of the simplest command? I have this warning when I use `help('modules')` in python shell. And python terminates

Comment: Use `strace -f` on Python and figure out why it's segfaulting. I don't use Ubuntu so I'm not too sure what can cause it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a popular bug of python on newer ubuntu versions. It has to do with the mixing of modules which have different bindings, see here:

http://blog.rabbitvcs.org/archives/312

I also have this problem and some suggestions how to solve it can be found here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836

Answer (score -1):

Use `help()` function, then enter the "interactive help" interface.

```
>>> help()

>>> help>
```

then enter:

```
>>> help> modules
```

This way is **available.**